# Update newly added rows of datagridview to oledb database using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledbconnection

I have a **`datagridview`** and an **Add** and **Save** button. Each time I add row to the **`datagridview`** with Add button and at the end save all rows to the database by Save button.

I want add/few few rows again to the *same* `datagriview` and then save to the database *but while saving new items to the database it takes whole datagridview rows again and saves to database.*

I wanted to save only new added data or edited data. Is there any way to set focus to the newly added rows or edited rows ? and at the end only saves the newly added or edited rows?

My datagridview always adds/inserts data to database at the end.

I am using below code for saving `datagridvew` rows to database :

```
                    int chkLoop;

                    chkLoop = dgvOrderList.Rows.Count;

                    MessageBox.Show(chkLoop.ToString());
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvOrderList.Rows)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(chkLoop.ToString());
                        //MessageBox.Show(row.co.ToString());
                        if (chkLoop != 1)
                        {
                            comm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Orders_Description (ItemCode, Quantity, Amount, OrderId, CreatedOn) VALUES ('" + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Code"].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Amount"].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderNo.Text) + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')", conn);
                            MessageBox.Show(comm.CommandText);

                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            chkLoop = chkLoop - 1;

                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm lazy to think.......
so you can add additional column with checkbox and whenever you add a new row the default value for the checkbox become selected and then when you are saving just check of that specific checkbox is checked or not.
if not checked it means it's not new row then continue to next iteration.

If you didn't got what I said comment below i will give you an example.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I got to know what you wanna say and i know this trick, but I want to know is there any other way to do this without using the check boxes?

Comment: OK I got your point, If I got time in the end of day i will try to see on my codes or in the web to help you.. 
But there is specific reason for not work with **DataAdapter**??

Comment: No any specific reason..!! I found working with OleDb is easier than DataAdapter.

Comment: Hey.. Felicio, do you got any solution on above problem?